# How to Get Data From a JSON File In Flask Server

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server running on my Pi. I have some data stored in a JSON file that another program produces. How can I load this data and send a part of it to the webpage? I tried doing the following:

```
import json

@application.route('/WebPage/')
def webPage():
    data = 0;
    with open("jsonFile.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return render_template("freeGame.html", header=data['title'])
```

But this just returns a 500 internal server error.
The json file looks like:
`{"title": "ExampleData"}`
and the webpage that takes the data looks like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>{ header }</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

I also can't get any information logged from flask as I'm running it with apache, so I can't tell if there's anything that flask has detected to be wrong. I tried getting the file with just `f=open("file.json", 'r')` and `f.close()` after, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Two things.  1. JSON requires double quotes, so if the file contents you provided actually look like that, you need to replace the single quotes with double quotes.  2.  You need two curly braces around your variable in your html file:  `{{ header }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly your code but I gave it a try to build a simple test example.
I got 3 files.

**./app.py**

```py
import json
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    fileData = 0;
    with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
      fileData = json.load(f)
      f.close()
    return render_template('index.html', fileData = fileData)
```

**./templates/index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> The message is: </h1>
        <h3>
            {{fileData["msg"]}}
        </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

**./data.json**

```
{
    "msg" : "This message is in a JSON File"
}
```

I get this output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> The message is: </h1>
        <h3>
            This message is in a JSON File
        </h3>
    </body>
</html>
```